# Unable to fit web page to viewport

Tags: html, css

I want the page to fit exactly the viewport and believed that the body properties below would work but I'm still getting a vertical scrollbar.

```
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: .8fr 4fr / 1fr 4fr;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if one of the other CSS properties I have might be affecting this? The codepen is at https://codepen.io/dkxp/pen/yLRVQNM. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the issue is on the `grid-template: .5fr 8fr .5fr / 2.5fr 1fr;`. update it with the proper size and it may resolve your issue.

Answer (score -2):

Your CSS is good. Usually, in this situation, the vertical scroll is introduced because of a child element. I would recommend that you comment out all of the child elements and then uncomment them one-by-one to see which element(s) caused the vertical scroll to be introduced.

Comment: Add this as a comment. If you have the code then add it here.

Comment: Rasyidi: To expand on @BhargavChudasama's point, this is providing recommendations on how to _debug_ this problem rather than an actual _solution_. That said, in this case, I'm not sure the question itself contains enough detail to properly answer the question (at least without relying on the external code link).

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to remove all properties from body...you can create this new section for grid properties.
May be this is a best way to do this.

Comment: Add this as a comment. If you have the code then add it here.

Comment: Nikhil, can you expand on what you mean? Are you suggesting that they move these properties from the `body` and into a new class that's more targeted? If so, why would you believe this to solve the issue with vertical scrolling? Without more detail, this answer is hard to understand or translate into actionable code.